# KAA server not starting after changing linux server timezone to UTC (PSQLException: FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "UTC")

Tags: kaa

Recently we have changed Linux server's timezone to UTC, (earlier it was EDT) but after this change, we are not able to access KAA admin URL. Getting below exception in logs.

How can we fix it, any help would be appreciated.

```
2018-10-05 14:49:07,500 [main] WARN  o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@68628510{/,jar:file:/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib/kaa-node-0.10.0.jar!/admin-web,STARTING}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.messaging.MessagingService org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.AbstractAdminService.messagingService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messagingService' defined in class path resource [admin-web/WEB-INF/adminContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326) ~[spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.control.service.admin.AdminContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(AdminContextLoaderListener.java:52) ~[kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:798) ~[jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:444) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:789) ~[jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1341) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1334) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741) ~[jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497) ~[jetty-webapp-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:380) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:347) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.control.service.admin.AdminInitializationService.start(AdminInitializationService.java:66) [kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.control.service.initialization.ControlInitializationService.start(ControlInitializationService.java:62) [kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.start(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.node.service.initialization.KaaNodeInitializationService.start(KaaNodeInitializationService.java:113) [kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.node.KaaNodeApplication.init(KaaNodeApplication.java:62) [kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.AbstractServerApplication.startAndWait(AbstractServerApplication.java:126) [server-shared-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.node.KaaNodeApplication.main(KaaNodeApplication.java:50) [kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.messaging.MessagingService org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.AbstractAdminService.messagingService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messagingService' defined in class path resource [admin-web/WEB-INF/adminContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messagingService' defined in class path resource [admin-web/WEB-INF/adminContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:544) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.dao.PropertiesFacade$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ecd8a275.getSpecificProperties(<generated>) ~[na:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.messaging.MessagingServiceImpl.configureMailSender(MessagingServiceImpl.java:115) ~[kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.messaging.MessagingServiceImpl.init(MessagingServiceImpl.java:94) ~[kaa-node-0.10.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1645) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "UTC")
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "UTC"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:574) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:177) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:138) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
```

The key error is

```
FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "UTC"
```

Comment: Made the actual error more obvious in a very long exception.

Comment: It could be related to this issue. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/382 Have you tried restarting the Postgress server after making the change?

Comment: Yes, restarted postgess and Kaa both.  I had checked this link earlier as well.. https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/382 , but i am not able to find out where should i make this change UTC to UTC+0 . It must be in some KAA configuration, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution.

Added below line in JAVA_OPTIONS in KAA config file, which resolved the issue.

-Duser.timezone=UTC+0

Its setting up the JVM timezone.